# Python - Spoofing a single method in a library - Handling Dead Queue- Djangoq/qcluster/SQS

Tags: python, django, amazon-sqs, django-q

I am using djangoq in my project ,and using sqs as broker.
As part of the system I enqueue some tasks which are taken by qcluster and executed. When some of the tasks are failed, they eventually end up in DEAD queue in SQS.

Now, If I put a qcluster in that queue, the task would be tried to be executed again. But what I want is to take the task, inspect the arguments, take the PK of the object model and then mark it failed. 
And I found the thing that I need to do is, create a new `worker` function.
and replace the default one.
https://github.com/Koed00/django-q/blob/master/django_q/cluster.py#L341

The problem is the default one is called directly from the scope in the file, and not passed as arguments to other methods.
So what I need to do is create an abstraction layer, which would import from djangoq package while injecting the new worker method into the package.
And then I would run qcluster from that abstraction layer.

But really dont know how to inject the new method and even that if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the whole code but you might (or not...) be able to make the thing work by monkeypatching `cluster.worker`:

```
from django_q import cluster
# in case you need to call the original implementation
original_worker = cluster.worker
def myworker(...):
   # your code here
cluster.worker = myworker

# now cluster will use `myworker`
```

But this is to be considered as a temporary workaround at best. The proper solution would be to fork djangoq so it only uses it's own `worker` function as default and let you pass any other callable.